# google map- Unable to get property 'TEXT_NODE' of undefined or null reference after API update

Tags: google-maps

I have replace new api key,  if i use

```
var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5,-0.11)
        }

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
```

it throws error as

> Unable to get property 'TEXT_NODE' of undefined or null reference

```
 <script 
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;key=xxxxx" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem accrue when i press on one of default googleMaps markers (like hospital and etc), and my website run from Windows forms WebBrowser control.
If this is your case try to add:
 
in the HTML file head section.
it should fix this problem because .Net WebBrowser are running as IE7 in default setting and this meta tag are help your site to run in other compatible mode